# Mixing debug and release in MSVC?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I got a program that has a quite simple 'load up' function that takes about 30 seconds (3M triangles that goes into std containers).
It works perfectly well.

The rest doesn't always (it is not finished) so I debug a lot I make a lot of changes and so on which means restarting quite often.

Is there any secret technique to compile the loader in release (which speeds up everything enormously) and leaving the rest as debug?

ps. I use MSVC 2005

Comment: Divide and conquer.  Make your code work first for 10 triangles.

Comment: You didn't get it right, it (the loading part) is already working perfectly well. It is slow though which mean 30+ sec to (re)launch a debug version (to debug other code). Thanks for your interest though.

Comment: No, test the *rest of your code* with 10 triangles.

Comment: Yes that would have worked but the rest of the code needs those data (If there are no 'easy solution' I'll build a tool that loads all the data into a memory block and saves it off on a file 'more easily exploitable' so that the program can just load it and update pointers etc. But in the end it won't make anything better as when the debugging (and creation) is finished, the start-up time is not of concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug builds tend to be very slow on Visual C++. There are a few reasons for this:

- the most obvious is that the code is not optimized
- the memory allocation functions in the debug CRT library perform additional checks to detect heap corruption and other issues, so they are slower.
- many STL functions perform additional validations and assertions on debug builds, which make use of STL containers very slow

I've had success debugging apps that make heavy use of memory and STL using the following method:

- use the release build for debugging (yes, this works fine!).
- configure your release builds to include debugging symbols, this should make the compiler write the .pdb file that the debugger uses
- only for the files you intend to debug, set the compiler to no optimizations.

Note that the above works great to debug problems in your own logic, but it may not be the best idea if you are debugging memory corruption or other problems, since you are eliminating all the extra debug code that the CRT provides for these types of issues.

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for debugging release builds. you get less support from the framework (less built-in checks), but if you're debugging your own logic, it would work well. IIRC, VC2005 creates PDB by default, so you don't need any extra configuration (but that might only be true to newer versions).

Comment: "only for the files you intend to debug, set the compiler to no optimizations." or the other way around, full optimisations for the part needed. But how do you do that in MSVC? (I do know my ways but not for that one).

Comment: Right click the file in question in the solution explorer and select Properties. There you can change any build settings and those changes will only affect the selected file.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing debug and release builds tends to go horribly wrong.

But there's no reason why you shouldn't turn on optimisation for some selected source files even in a debug build - and the optimisation should give you the performance improvements.

Comment: I believe the IDE allows you to set compilation options on individual files. Just enable optimisation on the loading part?